# Translating strings with multiple sections needing pluralization

Tags: php, symfony, translation

We're using the Symfony Translation component in our PHP application. It is capable of handling [pluralisation in a very clever way](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#pluralization), but as far as I can tell it can only handle a single "quantity" per string.

For example, it can translate

> I have 3 apples.

Or

> I have 1 orange.

But I can't work out a way to handle more complex strings like:

> I have 3 apples and 1 orange.

Now, the obvious solution is to translate them separately and then join them together, but in my real life situation the strings are more complicated than this and according to our German team the order of the components cannot always be guaranteed to be the same. Sticking with my fake apples and oranges example, we could have the English string:

> I'll have 3 apples each morning and 1 orange each weekday afternoon for the next 2 weeks.

I'd like to have a translation string like:

```
I'll have {{1 apple|%count_apples% apples}} each morning and {{1 orange|%count_oranges% oranges}} each weekday afternoon for the next {{1 week|%count_weeks% weeks}}.
```

And we need to consider that in another language, the structure of the sentence might only work if we use:

> For the next 2 weeks, I'll have 3 apples each morning and 1 orange each weekday afternoon.

```
For the next {{1 week|%count_weeks% weeks}}, I'll have {{1 apple|%count_apples% apples}} each morning and {{1 orange|%count_oranges% oranges}} each weekday afternoon.
```

To complicate things, further, the word for "and" might change depending on if one of the quantities is a plural. Right now, we're only bothered about English and German but will need other languages in the mid-term future and then there isn't even just a singular and plural.

We're open to using something other than the Symfony Translation component for this section if required as it is quite self-contained.

Does anybody have any past experience in this, or ideas as to how to go about implementing this?